# How do I install a customized font in system?? and copy to word pad?

Tags: fonts, font-size, font-face, truetype, truecrypt

I have designed a special character. what I want is I need to install to windows system.
First I want to assign that character to a keyboard. then when I copy this font from a word processor to word pad it should be visible.

I have modified glyph of an existing font and replaced "^" character to my new design.

Right now I have assigned this character to a "Shift+6^" button. and it is working in Microsoft word and Excel. but when I copy that to a word pad it wont show new character but shows "^" instead.

Is there a way to display my new character every where??

Answer (score 0):

It will only show up when typed in the font you modified, anywhere that uses a different font (i.e word pad) won't have the changed glyph.

Comment: Is there any way to do that??

Comment: I think we need to hack keyboard or typography kind of stuff...but anyone who knows this??